# How to apply CSS background color to some text in a paragraph without spaces caused by line-height?

Tags: css

I need the spacing between lines of text that line-height provides, but I also need to allow highlighting by setting background-color on parts of the text. I can do this easily enough, but the line-height gives white spaces between the lines.

Is there a way to get the background color to spread to the height given by line-height, rather than the font-size?

Comment: Are you applying the background color to an inline element by any chance?

Comment: Yes, it has to be a selection of text in a paragraph so cannot be display:block or display:inline-block, as these cause a line break effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can estimate the line height by adding some vertical padding to the element with the background color, but I guess that's about as close as you can get to being precise. The padding will not affect the line height, only the height of the background color.