# Extend background color of wrapped span when line-height is set and spacing appears between lines

Tags: css

I have a span of text that is wrapping and has some background color applied (as a highlight). Users can dynamically adjust the line-height of the text, but when this is done to a high enough value, white gaps appear between the lines of text. I'd like to fill/expand the lines so that the background color completely fills the gap, as though line-height was 1.

So far, the closest post I've found is one answered in 2012: [How to apply CSS background color to some text in a paragraph without spaces caused by line-height?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9700792/how-to-apply-css-background-color-to-some-text-in-a-paragraph-without-spaces-cau)

The answer to that was to adjust the padding based on the line-height. Since the line-height in my example is dynamic, that may not be so easy.

I would also like to maintain the format of the text (e.g. don't want to set display: inline-block).

At this point the only thing I can think of is to somehow calculate padding on-the-fly based on the line-height provided. I'm hoping that there is a more elegant solution out there.

Here is an example of what I'm running into: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/Jmeerw

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <span class="text">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor <span class="highlight">incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute</span> irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  </span>
  <div class="input-area">
    <div>Enter line-height in percent</div>
    <input id="line-height-input" type="number" value=200>%
  <div>
</div>
```

```css
.wrapper {
  width:600px; 
  margin: auto;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.input-area {
  padding-top: 20px;
}

.text {
  font-size:25px;
  line-height: 200%;
}

.highlight {
  background-color: lightgreen;
}
```

```js
$('#line-height-input').change(function(e) {
  $('.text').css('line-height', e.target.value + '%')
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set padding on the `highlight` span to increase its background area.

```js
$('#line-height-input').change(function(e) {
  $('.text').css('line-height', e.target.value + '%');
  // new:
  var padding = ((e.target.value-100)/200); if (padding<0) padding = 0;
  $('.highlight').css('padding-top', padding + 'em');
  $('.highlight').css('padding-bottom', padding + 'em');
})
```

```css
.wrapper {
  width:600px; 
  margin: auto;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.input-area {
  padding-top: 20px;
}

.text {
  font-size:25px;
  line-height: 200%;
}

.highlight {
  background-color: lightgreen;
  padding:.5em 0; /* initial, for a 2em lineheight */
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="wrapper">
  <span class="text">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor <span class="highlight">incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute</span> irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  </span>
  <div class="input-area">
    <div>Enter line-height in percent</div>
    <input id="line-height-input" type="number" value=200>%
  <div>
</div>
```

Comment: I ended up using this approach. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Another way to approach this is by using global css variables and the 'calc()' css function:

```js
// Doesn't matter if the 'font-size' or the 'line-height' changes, 
// the 'padding' will adjust accordingly.
$('#line-height-input').change(function(e) {
  $(':root').css('--line-height', (e.target.value/100.0) + 'em');
})
$('#font-size-input').change(function(e) {
  $(':root').css('--font-size', e.target.value + 'px');
})
```

```css
:root {
  --line-height: 1.5em;
  --font-size: 18px;
  /* The padding will adjusted automatically, allowing for more modulability */
  --font-padding: calc((var(--line-height) - var(--font-size))/2) 0;
}
.text {
  font-size:var(--font-size);
  line-height: var(--line-height);
}
.highlight { 
  background-color: lightgreen;
  padding: var(--font-padding);
}
/* Not important */
.wrapper { width:500px; display: inline-block;}
.input-area { padding: 0 10px 0 0; margin: 0 10px; border-right: 1px solid black; height:100%; display: inline-block; vertical-align:top; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="input-area">
  <div>Line Height </div>
  <input id="line-height-input" style="width:50px;" type="number" step=5 value=150> %
  <div>Font Size </div>
  <input id="font-size-input" style="width:50px" type="number" value=18> px
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
  <span class="text">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor <span class="highlight">incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute</span> irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. 
  </span>
</div>
```